# Read only for MS Access to remote MySql database

Tags: mysql, ms-access

I have created a MySQL database but I need to be able to create reports for it using MS Access.

Does anyone know of a way to gain read only access to a MySQL Database with MS Access? Perhaps by creating a macro or a file for MS Access?

Comment: I neglected to mention that this was remote access; using MS Access to get the information from various tables in the database.

Comment: If you wish to attach tables from MySQL to Access, it can be done through a wizard. If you want a read only account, it can be created through MySQL, AFAIK: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/adding-users.html

Answer (score 0):

You may create SQL Pass-Through Query and provide ODBC Connection string that connects to MySQL. The only additional stuff you need is MySQL ODBC driver on the machine you are running MS Access database.